# Why Excel charts' size cannot be set precisely via VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I'm trying to set the size of Excel charts via VBA and I noticed that often .ChartArea.Width and .ChartArea.Height properties set the values slightly differently than required. E.g. the code below:

```
Sub test_chart_area()
    Dim CA_w As Double
    Dim CA_h As Double
    CA_w = 500
    CA_h = 300
    With ActiveChart
        .ChartArea.Width = CA_w
        Debug.Print (".ChartArea.Width: " & .ChartArea.Width)
        .ChartArea.Height = CA_h
        Debug.Print (".ChartArea.Height: " & .ChartArea.Height)
    End With
End Sub
```

sets the chart to ".ChartArea.Width: 496.902204724409" and ".ChartArea.Height: 293.152125984252"

.PlotArea.InsideWidth and .PlotArea.InsideHeight properties, on the other hand, apparently assign only integer values. E.g. the code below:

```
Sub test_plot_area_inside()
    Dim PA_iw As Double
    Dim PA_ih As Double
    PA_iw = 200.411968503937
    PA_ih = 100.642677165354
    With ActiveChart
        .PlotArea.InsideWidth = PA_iw
        Debug.Print (".PlotArea.InsideWidth: " & .PlotArea.InsideWidth)
        .PlotArea.InsideHeight = PA_ih
        Debug.Print (".PlotArea.InsideHeight: " & .PlotArea.InsideHeight)
    End With
End Sub
```

sets the chart to ".PlotArea.InsideWidth: 200" and ".PlotArea.InsideHeight: 100".

The differences between the values required and returned are immaterial, but I'd like to understand the reason for this behaviour.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe this would have something to do with floating point values

Comment: Why not use a preset chart on a template and just dump the data in then save as? Would save quite a bit of code work and speed it up...

Answer (score 0):

Set the `.Width` and `.Height` properties of `ActiveChart.Parent`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works fine. By the way I realized that the result of setting ActiveChart.ChartArea.Width and ActiveChart.ChartArea.Height depends on the sheet's zoom level (e.g. ActiveChart.ChartArea.Width = 500 gives different results if run while the sheet that contains the chart is shown at 50% or 100% zoom level).